# call a function after a column is changed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to know when a column in my table is changed.

for example, if an user changed `fist-name` column , I would like to find out it (to call my custom function).

is there any `function/library/plugin` in laravel to help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You could hook into the model's updating event, check if the first name is being changed, and send an event. For instance:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        User::updating(function ($user) {
            if ($user->isDirty('first_name')) {
                event(FirstNameWasChanged::class);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Then you just have to write your notification logic in the event.